# UITextView into UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, insert, resize, uitextview

I'am noob. I need insert UITextView in to UITableViewCell with dynamic resizing and that i would typing right into cell. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You should mark Rog's answer as accepted so that this question is closed. (Both you and Rog will then be awarded reputation points.)

Answer (score 7):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell with a UITextField in it:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel *cellLabel;
    UITextField *cellTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *cellLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *cellTextField;

@end
```

And then implement:

```
@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize cellLabel, cellTextField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    ... // configure your label appearance here

        cellTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        ... // configure your textfield appearance here

    }

    return self;
}
```

And finally use your custom cells on:

```
- (CustomCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    ... // configure your cell data source here
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice reference implementation. (Might be a bit much for a beginner, but something to aim towards.)

Comment: No worries @Constantine. If you're happy with the answer please mark the question as answered as it helps improve my and your reputation in the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how the standard UITableView is designed to work. There's a defined way of adding/editing/removing items if that's what you're trying to achieve.

I'd recommend having a good read of the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) (specifically the "Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections" section) as this will put you on the right track.

You could of course create a custom view, etc. if you *really* want to allow users to type into a cell, but as a self-confessed "noob" I wouldn't recommend attempting this until you're more confident with the above approach, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree with this. What if you are implementing a form for users to type in to? A tableview with UITextFields is definitely a good solution for this and in fact it is used by Apple quite a bit (for instance when you're adding a new contact on the iPhone).

Comment: I was just thinking that for a beginner getting to know the standard way of doing things would be a good starting point before creating a custom view.

Comment: A beginner should learn the standard (proper) way of doing things. However, when they're asking more advanced questions, we're here to give them more advanced answers.

Comment: @W Dyson - And the advantage of SO is that the OP now has good links to both on one page. :-)